# vnc server gray out in ubuntu 15

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, gnome, graphics, vnc

Currently running Ubuntu 15.10 on azure and Installed vnc4server and gnome group packages but still screen showing gray out. configuration file is define below:

```
$cat .vnc/xstartup
unset SESSION_MANAGER
exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
x-window-manager &

gnome-panel &
gnome-settings-daemon &
metacity &
nautilus -n &
gnome-terminal &

$cat /etc/vncserver/vncservers.conf
VNCSERVERS="1:adminuser"
VNCSERVERARGS[1]="-geometry 1024x768"
```

Comment: You probably don't want to `exec` /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc or /etc/vnc/xstartup: `exec` **replaces** the current script process (so subsequent commands are not being executed). Try commenting out everything between `unset SESSION_MANAGER` and `gnome-panel &`

Comment: Still problem is same errror `Window manager warning: Missing composite extension required for compositing`  and `(gnome-settings-daemon:3337): rfkill-plugin-WARNING **: Could not open RFKILL control device, please verify your installation`
`

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice.